# How to insert an test case in a pool of existing test cases with priority

Tags: testng

I wrote 2 address related test cases in a class "address" having priority as 
@Test (priority =1)
@Test (priority =2)

Then i wrote 2 order related test cases in a class"order having priority as
@Test (priority =3)
@Test (priority =4)

lets assume that priority are huge in numbers.

Question : now if i want to add a new test case in address class. how to write that so that it get executed serially with other address related test cases.

Comment: Why do you use priority? Is there dependency between tests? Did you try  dependsOnMethods?

Comment: No there is not dependency between tests.. i just used to run in a sequence. If this is an wrong approach plz let me know the correct approach how to write test cases.

Comment: But why do you want to run them in sequence if there is no dependency between them?

Answer (score 0):

As [`priority`](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/Test.html#priority()) is an `int` you cannot "insert" a test using priorities if there are no available integer values to use between two given tests with set priorities.

If you don't mind your test not running if a previous test fails then you can use [`dependsOnMethods`](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/Test.html#dependsOnMethods()) along with [`priority`](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/Test.html#priority()):

```
@Test(priority = 1) public void test1() {}
@Test(priority = 2) public void test2() {}
@Test(priority = 3) public void test3() {}
@Test(priority = 4) public void test4() {}

// "insert" test between 2 and 3
@Test(priority = 2, dependsOnMethods = { "test2" }) public void test2b() {}
```

However, if you want to strictly use priorities then you can define some static constants to help in "inserting" tests so that you don't have to manually re-order test priorities each time you want to "insert" a test:

**Before inserting a new test**

```
static final int TEST_1_PRIORITY = 1;
static final int TEST_2_PRIORITY = TEST_1_PRIORITY + 1;     // evaluates to 2
static final int TEST_3_PRIORITY = TEST_2_PRIORITY + 1;     // evaluates to 3
static final int TEST_4_PRIORITY = TEST_3_PRIORITY + 1;     // evaluates to 4

@Test(priority = TEST_1_PRIORITY) public void test1() {}
@Test(priority = TEST_2_PRIORITY) public void test2() {}
@Test(priority = TEST_3_PRIORITY) public void test3() {}
@Test(priority = TEST_4_PRIORITY) public void test4() {}
```

**After inserting a new test**

```
static final int TEST_1_PRIORITY = 1;
static final int TEST_2_PRIORITY = TEST_1_PRIORITY + 1;     // still evaluates to 2
static final int TEST_2b_PRIORITY = TEST_2_PRIORITY + 1;    // evaluates to 3
static final int TEST_3_PRIORITY = TEST_2b_PRIORITY + 1;    // now evaluates to 4
static final int TEST_4_PRIORITY = TEST_3_PRIORITY + 1;     // now evaluates to 5

@Test(priority = TEST_1_PRIORITY) public void test1() {}
@Test(priority = TEST_2_PRIORITY) public void test2() {}
@Test(priority = TEST_2b_PRIORITY + 2) public void test2b() {}
@Test(priority = TEST_3_PRIORITY) public void test3() {}
@Test(priority = TEST_4_PRIORITY) public void test4() {}
```